# How to calculate total field and set it into data with use hook form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms

Hello i am new to using use hook form and im trying to complete a form which takes membership type, price and calculate the total price based on the membership type. Also display it into the disabled total price input field.

```
const AddMember = () => {
  const form = useForm<Member>(
    {
      defaultValues: {
        assignedBy: 'admin',
        name: '',
        lastName: '',
        gender: '',
        membershipType: '',
        startingDate: '',
        total: 0
      },
      resolver: yupResolver(ValidationSchema)
    }
  );
  const { register, control, handleSubmit, formState, watch } = form;
  const { isDirty, errors } = formState;
  const watchMembershipType = watch('membershipType');
  const watchPrice = watch('price');
  type Member = {
    assignedBy: string
    name: string
    lastName: string
    gender: string
    phone: number
    membershipType: string
    startingDate: string
    price: number
    total: number
  }
  let totalPrice: number;
  const calculatePrice = (data: Member) => {
    switch (watchMembershipType) {
      case '1 month':
        data.total = watchPrice;
        totalPrice = watchPrice;
        break;
      case '3 months':
        data.total = (watchPrice * 3) - (watchPrice * 3) * 0.1;
        totalPrice = (watchPrice * 3) - (watchPrice * 3) * 0.1;
        break;
      case '1 year':
        data.total = (watchPrice * 12) - (watchPrice * 12) * 0.2;
        totalPrice = (watchPrice * 12) - (watchPrice * 12) * 0.2;
        break;
    }
  }


  const onSubmit = (data: Member) => {
    calculatePrice(data);
    console.log(totalPrice);
    console.log(data);
  }
      return (
        <div className='add-member'>
         {/*..previos code of the form..*/}
              <div className='input' id='price-input'>
                <label>Price </label>
                <input {...register('price')} placeholder='$ (per month)' className={errors.price?.message ? 'error' : ''} />
              </div>
              <div className='input' id='price-total'>
                <label>Total</label>
                {/* <input value={`${totalPrice}`} {...register('total')} disabled={true} />   */}
              </div>
              <button type='submit' disabled={!isDirty}>Submit</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <DevTool control={control} />
        </div>
      )
    }
    export default AddMember
```

EDITED: I managed to set the total price into the data object, by directly changing the property value without setting it into a different state, since i wasnt getting any error. Now im just trying to make the value of total input change when im changing the type of membership/price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to mention that React is not working in this way - reassigning of variable is not triggering re rendering of a component. In the function calculatePrice, there is a reassignment of the variable totalPrice, but it do not trigger re rendering and for that you can not see any change on the page. There a lot of ways to do that in React, I will show really simple way:

```
 const calculatePrice = (data: Member) => {
    let totalPrice: number;
    switch (watchMembershipType) {
        case "1 month":
            data.total = watchPrice;
            totalPrice = watchPrice;
            setCalculatedTotal(totalPrice);
            break;
        case "3 months":
            data.total = watchPrice * 3 - watchPrice * 3 * 0.1;
            totalPrice = watchPrice * 3 - watchPrice * 3 * 0.1;
            setCalculatedTotal(totalPrice);
            break;
        case "1 year":
            data.total = watchPrice * 12 - watchPrice * 12 * 0.2;
            totalPrice = watchPrice * 12 - watchPrice * 12 * 0.2;
            setCalculatedTotal(totalPrice);

            break;
    }
};
```

I've added a state variable with useState hook. When the user fills in the form and hits Submit, now the function calculateTotal calculates the total and set the value in state. That triggers rerender of the component and the value is shown.

Other way is to use the state of the useForm hook:

```
 const calculatePrice = (data: Member) => {
    let totalPrice: number;
    switch (watchMembershipType) {
        case "1 month":
            data.total = watchPrice;
            totalPrice = watchPrice;
            setValue("total", totalPrice);
            break;
        case "3 months":
            data.total = watchPrice * 3 - watchPrice * 3 * 0.1;
            totalPrice = watchPrice * 3 - watchPrice * 3 * 0.1;
            setValue("total", totalPrice);
            break;
        case "1 year":
            data.total = watchPrice * 12 - watchPrice * 12 * 0.2;
            totalPrice = watchPrice * 12 - watchPrice * 12 * 0.2;
            setValue("total", totalPrice);

            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i changed it this way.
  `useEffect(() => {`
    `switch (watchMembershipType) {`
      `case '1 month':`
        `setCalculatedTotal(watchPrice * 1)`
       `break;`
        `case '3 months':`
        `setCalculatedTotal((watchPrice * 3) - (watchPrice * 3) * 0.1)`
        `break;`
      `case '1 year':`
        `setCalculatedTotal((watchPrice * 12) - (watchPrice * 12) * 0.2)`
        `break;`
    `}`
  `}, [watchPrice, watchMembershipType]);`
 
Since i wanted total to show/change before submitting. Seems to be working.

Comment: It works, but it is not the best way to do it. The hook useEffect is only for synchronize a component with external data. I recommend you to read an article from the official documentation - [Not needed effect](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#you-might-not-need-an-effect) . I would use derived state. Bare in mind comments are not for posting code.